# Android, iPhone: Add own adverts to App

Tags: iphone, android, ads

I am building an App for a company that contains 'sponsors' (ads in form of banners).
Does anyone know if this is allowed or if Apple/Google will not accept an App like that?

Comment: How are you building an app without having used either one? Anyone who has an Android or iPhone knows that there are lots and lots of apps with banner ads. Hell, Google and Apple both own smartphone advertising platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got an app with a custom banner system accepted to appstore.

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant custom banners. Thanks.